Laravel Sanctum Login And Register API with React js
I have a created my api in laravel using sanctum for user login and register and am getting this error
xhr.js:258 
 POST http://jaano.test/api/login 419 (unknown status)
settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 419', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
adapter
: 
(2) ['xhr', 'http']
baseURL
: 
"http://jaano.test"
data
: 
"{\"email\":\"kofi@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"123456789\"}"
env
: 
{FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders {Accept: 'application/json', Content-Type: 'application/json', Authorization: ''}
maxBodyLength
: 
-1
maxContentLength
: 
-1
method
: 
"post"
timeout
: 
0
transformRequest
: 
[ƒ]
transformResponse
: 
[ƒ]
transitional
: 
{silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}
url
: 
"/api/login"
validateStatus
: 
ƒ validateStatus(status)
withCredentials
: 
true
xsrfCookieName
: 
"XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName
: 
"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 419"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: {…}, status: 419, statusText: 'unknown status', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 419\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78750:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:77432:66)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error

But my api is working perfectly when I call it in postman or thunder client, and am sure the issue is with the react js code
App.js file
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios";

import "./App.css";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Listing from "./components/Listing";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import BestDeals from "./components/BestDeals";
import VendorProducts from "./components/VendorProducts";
import ProductDetails from "./components/ProductDetails";
import SearchProduct from "./components/SearchProduct";
import Wishlist from "./components/Wishlist";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";
import Checkout from "./components/Checkout";
import Thanks from "./components/Thanks";
import Orders from "./components/Orders";
import OrderDetails from "./components/OrderDetails";
import Courses from "./components/Courses";
import CourseCategory from "./components/CourseCategory";
import CourseDetails from "./components/CourseDetails";
import SearchCourse from "./components/SearchCourse";
import FavouriteCourses from "./components/FavouriteCourses";
import Blogs from "./components/Blogs";
import BlogCategory from "./components/BlogCategory";
import BlogTag from "./components/BlogTag";
import BlogDetails from "./components/BlogDetails";
import BlogVideoDetails from "./components/BlogVideoDetails";
import SearchBlog from "./components/SearchBlog";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import ProfileSettings from "./components/ProfileSettings";
import VendorRegister from "./components/VendorRegister";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import ErrorPage from "./components/ErrorPage";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://jaano.test";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Accept"] = "application/json";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
  config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "";
  return config;
});

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/listing" element={<Listing />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/best-deals" element={<BestDeals />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/vendor-products"
            element={<VendorProducts />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/product-details"
            element={<ProductDetails />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/search-product"
            element={<SearchProduct />}
          ></Route>
          <Route exact path="/wishlist" element={<Wishlist />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/cart" element={<Cart />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/thanks" element={<Thanks />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/orders" element={<Orders />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/order-details" element={<OrderDetails />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/courses" element={<Courses />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/course-category"
            element={<CourseCategory />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/course-details"
            element={<CourseDetails />}
          ></Route>
          <Route exact path="/search-course" element={<SearchCourse />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/favourite-courses"
            element={<FavouriteCourses />}
          ></Route>
          <Route exact path="/blogs" element={<Blogs />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/blog-category" element={<BlogCategory />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/blog-tag" element={<BlogTag />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/blog-details" element={<BlogDetails />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/search-blog" element={<SearchBlog />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/blog-video-details"
            element={<BlogVideoDetails />}
          ></Route>
          {/* <Route exact path="/login">
            {localStorage.getItem("auth_token") ? (
              <Redirect to="/" />
            ) : (
              <Login />
            )}
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/register">
            {localStorage.getItem("auth_token") ? (
              <Redirect to="/" />
            ) : (
              <Register />
            )}
          </Route> */}
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/profile-settings"
            element={<ProfileSettings />}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/vendor-register"
            element={<VendorRegister />}
          ></Route>
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/404" element={<ErrorPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Register.js file
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import axios from "axios";

// import axios from "./axios";

function Register() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [registerInput, setRegister] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    mobile: "",
    password: "",
    error_list: [],
  });

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({ ...registerInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const registerSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: registerInput.name,
      email: registerInput.email,
      mobile: registerInput.mobile,
      password: registerInput.password,
    };

    axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
      axios.post(`/api/register`, data).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 201) {
          localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);
          localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.username);
          swal("Success", res.data.message, "success");
          navigate("/");
        } else {
          setRegister({
            ...registerInput,
            error_list: res.data.validation_errors,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <section className="login-box">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-3"></div>
          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <div className="input-box">
              <header>Create Account</header>
              <form onSubmit={registerSubmit}>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    name="name"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.name}
                  />
                  <label>Full Name</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.name}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="input"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.email}
                  />
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.email}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    name="mobile"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.mobile}
                  />
                  <label>Mobile</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.mobile}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="input"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.password}
                  />
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.password}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="ps-2 pb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" className="me-1" name="" id="" />
                  <Link to="/terms-conditions">
                    Agree to our terms and conditions
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <button type="submit" className="login-submit">
                    Register
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div className="signin">
                <div className="signup pb-2">
                  <span>
                    <Link to="/login">Already has an account?</Link>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <span className="pb-2">
                  <Link to="#">Forgot password?</Link>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Register;

Login.js file
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import axios from "axios";

// import axios from "./axios";

function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loginInput, setLogin] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    error_list: [],
  });

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setLogin({ ...loginInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const loginSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      email: loginInput.email,
      password: loginInput.password,
    };

    axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
      axios.post(`/api/login`, data).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 201) {
          localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);
          localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.username);
          swal("Success", res.data.message, "success");
          navigate("/");
        } else if (res.data.status === 401) {
          swal("Warning", res.data.message, "warning");
        } else {
          setLogin({
            ...loginInput,
            error_list: res.data.validation_errors,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <section className="login-box log">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4"></div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <div className="input-box">
              <header>Sign In</header>
              <form onSubmit={loginSubmit}>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="input"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={loginInput.email}
                  />
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {loginInput.error_list.email}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="input"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={loginInput.password}
                  />
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {loginInput.error_list.password}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="ps-2 pb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" className="me-1" name="" id="" />
                  Remember me
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <button type="submit" className="login-submit">
                    Login
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="signin">
                  <div className="signup pb-2">
                    <span>
                      <Link to="/register">Don't have an account?</Link>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <span className="pb-2">
                    <Link to="#">Forgot password?</Link>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Login;


Any help?
I am expecting to get the react codes correct and also prevent csrf token error and login or register to my react js website successfully

When I inspect the error in console, i get {message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…} exception :  "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException" file :  "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\jaano\\jaanobackend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php" line :  389 message :  "CSRF token mismatch."
